# Laravel response()->json in custom class return empty string

Tags: php, json, laravel

i have one problem, and I cant solve it.

In my controller i have method:

```
public function deleteImg(Request $request, $id) {
        $image_id  = $request->input('imgId');
        $image_src = $request->input('imgSrc');
        AdImages::delete($id, $image_id, $image_src);
    }
```

Inside of AdImages class I have static method:

```
public static function delete($id, $image_id, $image_src) {
    return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Error occurred. Please try again.']);
}
```

And here is ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/dashboard/ad/{{ $ad->id }}/remove-image',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {imgId: imgId, imgSrc: imgSrc},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
```

Problem is if i return response i got nothing, empty string. But if i var dump(response()->...) i see object i need.

Any ideas/suggestions ?

Thank you

Comment: Instead of `return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Error occurred. Please try again.'])` do `echo` that array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller method isn't actually returning anything to the browser. You should put the return json response call in your controller method, not in your model.

I'd also advise you not to name model methods "delete", as that's an Eloquent keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Add a return to AdImages call:

```
return AdImages::delete($id, $image_id, $image_src);
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys.
that was the problem :)

And yes, it would be smart to rename delete to something else.